# how to fix interval on UISlider,iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have Slider,which works perfect.
But what i am trying to do is,
for ex, min =0 and max=50 and x=0
every time i slide or use buttons to change the value of slider,  the interval should be of 5 only.
i.e x should be equal to only 0,5,10,15.....50

Suggestions.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the callback (value changed) - read the value, round it up or down to the nearest increment of 5, then set the slider to your preferred value. That way, it will 'jump' between your preferred values.